# why actorSystem will been deprecated in spark

Tags: apache-spark

When I read the spark core sources, I feel confused why the actorsystem will be deprecated since spark 1.4.0, is there problem when use actorSystem in akka? what about the DAGEventProcessActor and DriverActor?

Comment: They have decided to bring Spark closer to bare metal with the Tungsten project.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason has more to do with proper encapsulation of access to internal Akka resources from external clients (e.g anything not directly related with Spark core). I believe this is because the Spark devs do not want Spark to be tightly coupled with Akka, and the reasons for this, AFAIK are:

1. A decision might be taken in future releases to remove Akka as the main engine for internal communication
2. Spark has stricter versioning guidelines than Akka. Quoting from this [Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2593)

> The reason that we don't want to expose Akka classes in public APIs is that Spark has stricter versioning guidelines than Akka: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Spark+Versioning+Policy
>
> Basically, all of Spark 1.X is going to be backward-compatible, so that means that we might get stuck with an old version of Akka that we have to maintain, which won't link with user's new versions of Akka

In that same thread:

> [...] concern isn't so much upgrades, it's locking users in to a specific Akka version. For example, suppose we add an API involving classes from Akka 2.2 today, and later 2.3 or 2.4 changes those classes in a way that isn't compatible. Then to meet our API stability promises to our users, we're going to keep our version of Akka at 2.2, and users simply won't be able to use a new Akka in the same application as Spark